# llevar archivo y un usuario a la base de datos,

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, html5, laravel

esta es la vista  que lleva los datos, el archivo y el nombre pero al llegar al controlador solo envia el archivo

```
  <input type="file" name="link"  required="required">
  <textarea type="text"  rows="50" hidden="hidden" id="textosid"   name="cliente" ></textarea>
  <button type="submit" id="bot" class="btn btn-primary">Subir Boletín</button>


public function store(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->hasFile('link','cliente')){
            $cliente = $request->file('cliente');
            $link = $request->file('link');
            $file_name = time().$link->getClientOriginalName();
            $link->move(public_path().'/boletines/'.$file_name);
        }
        $file = new File();
        $file->cliente = $cliente;
        $file->name = $link->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->link = $file_name;
        $file->save();
        Session::flash('Exito','Boletin Guardado');
        return Redirect::to('file/create');
        ///view('file.create');
    }
```

este es el model

```
    protected $table = 'files'; // Nombre de la tabla que se va a llamar 
    protected $primaryKey = 'id'; // Clave primaria para identificar el usuario.
    protected $fillable = [ 'name','link','cliente'];/// los datos.
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. No uses aquí etiquetas `<pre> </pre>`. No ayudan, el código se hace invisible. Para mostrar código sólo pégalo, luego selecciona todo el bloque de código y pulsa sobre los símbolos **`{ }`** que aparecen en la parte superior. Por otra parte, explica mejor tu problema, porque no se entiende con claridad lo que pasa. Y si da algún error, agrégalo a la pregunta. Para hacer cualquier cambio en ella, [la puedes editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/209466/edit). Gracias.

Comment: Gracias lo voy a tener presente 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si el submit envía un file y un textarea, yo veo varios errores:

1) Si el textarea tiene de name: cliente, hasFile debería de llevar solos tipos file. Además, la siguiente sentencia tampoco sería lógica, quedaría así:

```
 if($request->hasFile('link')){
      $cliente = $request->input('cliente');
```

2) Si declaras las variables $link, $file_name, y $cliente en la condición del IF, y no se cumple, cuando llegue a la parte de:

```
$file = new File();
$file->cliente = $cliente;
$file->name = $link->getClientOriginalName();
$file->link = $file_name;
$file->save();
Session::flash('Exito','Boletin Guardado');
return Redirect::to('file/create');
///view('file.create');
```

Esas variables no van a existir en ese contexto.